# Search results different from other account?

Tags: search, search-results

i have 2 different account for the same sharepoint site,

the first account is able to search documents for the search engine,

the second account with the same search text is unable to search anything, it just returns Zero records.

The second account has read permissions to the site, but why cant it search any documents like the first account does ?

Answer (score 3):

The search results are security trimmed which means only those results are displayed which user has rights to view.

If the second account is not having permissions on the documents\items, they will not appear in search results.

Comment: And note that it was the permission a Crawl time if you've added user2 to the list after last full crawl. Items will not show up until new full crawl or they are changed and caught by incremental crawl

Answer (score 1):

Can users with read permissions just view library documents throught GUI?

If not, the documents are maybe in "draft" state and users with read permission can't see or read them because of Draft Item security like Amit wrote hours ago.

Check Library Settings > Versioning settings and  Draft Item Security checkboxes. This is confusing for our users every day.